# How to turn a series that contains pandas.datetime.timedelta to floats e.g. hours or days?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to plot some data that contains timedeltas. However, the numpy `plot()` and `errorbar()` return:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timedelta'
```

The question is how can I efficiently convert the timedeltas to a float or integer number. E.g. when I use minutes as base:

```
0 days 01:30:00 -> 90
```

or hours

```
0 days 01:30:00 -> 1.5
```

Similar to `Series.dt.days` which would return 0 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use `Series.dt.seconds` and ´Series.dt.days´ and  multiply with a factor for the desired unit:

```
(Series.dt.seconds/3600) + (Series.dt.days*24)  # for values with [hours]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide by the timedelta you want to use as unit:

```
totalDays = my_timedelta = pd.TimeDelta('1D')
```